# Querydsl configuration for Gradle 7.4.2

Tags: java, jpa, gradle, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have a Gradle project into which I want to implement Java class with querydsl. I tried this implementation:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.7'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'test'
version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.2")
    queryDslVersion = '5.0.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10.14'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:2.6.7'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    implementation 'org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:7.0.0.CR1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:3.1.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'

    // QueryDSL
    implementation "com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:${queryDslVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${queryDslVersion}:jpa"
    testImplementation "com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:${queryDslVersion}"
    testAnnotationProcessor "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${queryDslVersion}:jpa"
    
    // Lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    // Swagger
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.8'

    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

But JPA classes are not generated. I get exception:

```
import com.test.domain.QTransaction;
                       ^
  symbol:   class QTransaction
  location: package com.test.domain
```

Do you know what is the proper way to implement this?

Comment: I had QueryDsl working with Gradle 6.9 but when upgraded to 7.2, Qclasses generation stopped working, Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Working configuration for Spring Cloud `2021.0.8`/Spring Boot `2.6.15` and Gradle `8.3`

```
implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:5.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.2.Final'
annotationProcessor 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jpa'
```